# Can 'angle' be used as verb to mean 'to fish'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs

Can 'angle' be used as a verb in the sense 'to fish'? If so, is it an American usage?

Comment: When you say "is it an American usage?" are asking if it's used at all in America or if it's an exclusively American usage?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a dictionary will easily tell you that _angling_ refers to a specific type of fishing; the other part of the OP's question, about its American-ness, needs to be clarified, as KillingTime said.

Comment: A specific type of fishing? Are you sure of that? @Heartspring

Comment: Merriam-Webster has as the most relevant meaning of "[angle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/angles)" as "to fish with a hook". A dictionary will tell you if it's primarily US or UK, but it will depend on areas where fishing with a hook and line is common.

Comment: Angling seems to be a sport, whereas fishing is an industry.

Comment: Fishing isn't *only* an industry. It can be sport,  leisure activity, means of subsistence, or industry.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? Dictionaries have sentence examples. Try [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/angle#dictionary-entry-3) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/angling) If you don't find any, then edit the question and tell us. You're more likely to get an answer if you share your research.

Comment: angling is a sport. No doubt about it. If you fish for a living, that is not called angling even if the person is fishing with a rod and line. It is most definitely **not** an American usage: It is used in Australian, New Zealand, English, Scottish, American, Canadian and South African and "who-knows-what-other" English-speaking country.

Comment: This is one of those "hadda be there" questions. No one fishes here? I come from a family of anglers. The rich and snobby ones go to all sorts of lengths to go fishing in the wilds of this or that place. They go to places like Iceland and helicopter in to fly fish the salmon. It really turns my stomach.

Comment: I'd say only the ing-form of the verb is common, in the phase structure ('they often go  angling') and as the regular past participle ('they were angling for pike').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's funny because where I fish, they would say fishin' for pike. A truly nasty looking creature, that also can bite if you  don't know how to land them.

Comment: @Lambie You haven't read Bickerdyke's 'Angling for Pike'? A classic.

Answer (score 1):

One fishes for fish.

**Angling is a type of fishing** that involves fishing with a rod, line and hook and lure (bait or a fly). There is fly rod fishing and fishing with a spinning rod. Both are angling.

The verb is not used to say to things like "I angle fish", usually. However, **the person is known as an angler**.

Also, **fishing like this** is often referred to as angling in BrE, AmE etc. in freshwater or saltwater And the person is an angler. Compare that to **fisherman**, which is usually a profession.

"I like angling" is accurate and is used.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that *angling*, as in fishing with a hook, may be part of the etymology of the Angles and so of England and English.

Comment: @Henry Indeed. But it probably includes a rod; it is not line fishing.

Answer (score 0):

The two verbs also overlap in meaning in their figurative senses when used with *for*.

> **angle** (v.)
>
> *Figurative*
>
> *Intransitive*. To seek to ensnare or acquire a person or thing; (in later use esp.) to seek to elicit a particular reaction, response,
> opinion, etc., as by indirectly prompting someone to offer it; **to
> ‘fish’**. Usually with *for*.
>
> **2001** More recently the term has transmogrified into a despicable phraseological device employed by honkies **angling for** hipster
> credibility.
> *Vanity Fair* (New York) November 284/1
> OED online

> **fish for** (phrasal verb)
>
> To ask for or try to get (something, such as praise or attention) in
> an indirect way
>
> *I think he offers apologies for his cooking as a way of **fishing for** compliments.*
> *Fishing for answers*
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fish%20for)

> **fish** (v.)
>
> To try to get something, without asking directly
>
> *She was always fishing, hoping I'd say something about Sarah.*
>
> **fish for**   *The director was fishing for information about our strategy.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fish)